# AnzoGraph docker support for Mac m1

Tags: macos, docker, graph-databases, apple-m1, anzograph

I have been trying to get AnzoGraph installed through docker in my Mac m1, but it seems this can work only on x86 architecture.

Do you know if there is any other way of having it install in my Mac?

Thank you!